# ng-app making the script run to infinity

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angular application using asp.net web application empty template and i have a problem with using ng-app, when i use it and lave it blank i the $routeProvider doesn't get instantiated, but when i specify ng-app="myApp" to my module name, the content of the body starts to repeat to infinite loop.
I'm sure i'm missing something basic, but this problem is driving me crazy
thanks

here's my html code

## this is main

```
<a href="#/view1">view1</a>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and here's myApp code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config([
        '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'index.html',
                controller: 'main'
            }).when('/view1', {
                templateUrl: 'view1.html',
                controller: 'main'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }
    ]);

    app.controller('main', function ($scope) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("from set");
        },10000);
    });
})();
```

Comment: There is nothing shown that would do what you say about infinite loop. Show more of the code and the view that is causing issues. Also note any errors in browser console

Comment: how do you specify your ng-app where you said that you got infinite loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is that `index.html` is not the template that should be loaded into the `ng-app`, it is the outer shell page.  You are loading the entire app inside itself over and over, producing something like the following:

```html
<a href="#/view1">view1</a>

<div>
  <a href="#/view1">view1</a>

  <div>
    <a href="#/view1">view1</a>

    <div>
      <a href="#/view1">view1</a>

      <div>
        //...  more and more loaded here
      </div>
      <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </div>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

... essentially forever.

You should instead be loading only templates in your routes.

Answer (score 2):

Is your default route loading the page into itself?

```
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html', <----- ???
        controller: 'main'
    })
```

Comment: Yep exactly. Routes should only load partial htmls, since loading the main html (which is already being loaded) causes an infinite recursive loop. Surprised the inner ng-view isn't ignored though

Comment: thank you guys , the problem was solved , u helped me a lot

Comment: @ahmedGomaa To help people with similar problems, please one of the questions as correct if it helped you out. Otherwise add an answer yourself describing how you fixed the problem.